# No tensorflow in Google Colaboratory local host

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, google-colaboratory

There is no tensorflow in google colab local host machine and there is no way to install it. When I run train.py it shows no module named 'tensorflow'.I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: not suitable versions..

Comment: remember I m on the local runtime

Comment: and I am not even able to use venv or docker to get tensorflow running

Comment: I know literally nothing about this topic, just trying to rule out the simple issues <3

Comment: I assume the line that errors is just `import tensorflow`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no one-size-fits-all way to install TensorFlow on your local machine. (Part of the value of Colab's backends is dealing with all of that.)

Fortunately, TensorFlow does have a fairly comprehensive set of install steps for most common environments; see: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

My recommendation is to start there, try to work through the process, and, if you hit a snag, ask a follow-up question that describes your OS, install type, what you tried, and the error you encountered.